# Ubuntu 14.04 how do I install the proprietary fglrx drivers without crashing at startup?

Tags: drivers

I have recently been using the x.org open source drivers and they haven't been giving me the performance I like. So I was wondering how can I change to the fglrx proprietary drivers without getting stuck on the purple boot screen and crashing. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If ubuntu is getting stuck on login window , my suggestion would be to install those drivers from run-level.
you can jump to run level by pressing `ctrl+shift+Esc` during booting
after that run this command

```
sudo lightdm stop
```

it will stop the lightdm server,then you can install those drivers from terminal.
after that restart the lightdm server & reboot the computer.

Comment: OK I'll try this later today. But what would happen is I would use an proprietary driver and then restart. Then I would boot and get stuck at the Ubuntu loading sign and just sit there. Again thanks